# connecting to a socket

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, irc

```
         arg = data.split( )   

         args = '' 
         for index,item in enumerate(arg) : 
              if index > 3: 
                  if args == '': 
                      args = item 
                  else : 
                          args += ' ' + item


  if data.find('!check') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     ip = args[1]
     port = int(args[2])
     try:
         s.connect((ip, port))
         s.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" ' its alive' + '\r\n')
     except socket.error:
         s.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" ' its dead' + '\r\n')
```

I'm trying to connect to a proxy to see if its alive or dead, but I keep getting this error..

```
port = int(args[2]) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'
```

Comment: How should we  know what args[2] is? The debugger is your friend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What arguments are you giving your code? The `ValueError` is telling you that you're trying to convert a period (`.`) to an integer, which makes no sense. What is `args`?

Comment: your code is pointless and does not tell us anything about 'args'. Read my comment above and debug your code. Your information is incomplete and incohrent.

Comment: Yeah, no idea what `data` looks like, so the rest doesn't make any sense. Also, you're treating `args` like a list later on in the code, but your `for` loop builds a string.